# How to change language locally in react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to give user an option to specify language of generated receipt while keeping the language of the app the same. How would I change the language only for receipt component? `i18n.changeLanguage` does it globally.

If it helps, here is my i18n config:

```
i18n
.use(Backend)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    ns: ["translation", "login", "orders", "products", "invoices"],
    defaultNS: "translation",
    lng: "sl",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },
    react: {
        useSuspense: true,
        wait: true,
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you add your `i18next` config?

Comment: You can create an additional i18next instance and use its t function to translate receipts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getFixedT` method to get translations of a particular object in a given language regardless of the global language. Here is an example:

**en.json**

```json
{
 nested: {
  object: {
   ...
  }
 }
}
```

**App.jsx**

```js
import { getFixedT } from "i18next";

const App = () => {
  const fixedT = getFixedT("en");
  const templateData = fixedT("nested.object", {
      returnObjects: true,
    });
}
```

**References**

i18next official documentation: [getFixedT](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#getfixedt)